# Override method not found in Java Binding Library on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wrapper

I'm creating a Java Binding Library for Xamarin.Forms in order to wrap a .jar library.

I got a couple of errors while compiling.

I already solved an issue given by multiple methods having the same signature using "Metadata.xml" in "Transforms" section.

Still, the compiler keeps on bringing out that an appropriate override for this method can't be found:

```
[Register ("compareTo", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)I", "GetCompareTo_Ljava_lang_Object_Handler")]
public override unsafe int CompareTo (global::Java.Lang.Object o)
{
    const string __id = "compareTo.(Ljava/lang/Object;)I";
    try {
        JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue [1];
        __args [0] = new JniArgumentValue ((o == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : ((global::Java.Lang.Object) o).Handle);
        var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractInt32Method (__id, this, __args);
        return __rm;
    } finally {
        global::System.GC.KeepAlive (o);
    }
}
```

Additionally, the owning class of the up method has NO METADATA REFERENCE, as well as the method itself doesn't have one. This makes it difficult even to try removing the node in "Metadata.xml".

To give you a clue, the method "CompareTo" can be found in the following class:

```
Java.Nio.Charset.Charset
```

that basically is the class the generator inherits in order to create a

```
public abstract partial class CustomCharset
```

Before I try to ignore the entire class, with unexpected consequences on the app I'm about to develop, I would like to know if anyone has ever gone through something similar please. How to solve?

Comment: what language are we talking about here? Java? Then why the C# tag?

Comment: @Stultuske - that is c# code, running in xamarin.android. Part of a c# wrapper of a java library. Thus the obscure syntax and type references.